# How to load heavy data?

Tags: angularjs

I am getting 5000 list of user and their details from server and am trying to show those records . Records are displayed but am seeing continues loading.. and after loading am not able to do anything. Is there any solution to load 5000 records without loading and crashing?

Comment: Please show us what've you tried so far!

Comment: You can lazy load the data as the user scrolls through the table. And even better if the data is just displayed you can also use one time binding {{:: val}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with loading 5000 records isn't (only) that you're receiving a lot of data, but that Angular has to process all that in the digest cycle. I'll bet that if you do a profiling in the browser, you'll find most of the CPU time is spend in the digest loop.

To avoid that you have to only allow a limited number of DOM elements on the page at a time. As suggested, one way of doing this is using paging.

Another way, where you still load your 5000 records, is to use a concept called virtual repeat/scroll, where you have a directive that only shows the elements that can fit in your viewport (i.e. on the users screen) and then whenever the user scrolls, the directive adds more elements below, while removing elements that goes out of view. This can be done seamless and can have a huge impact on performance.

Virtual repeat/scroll can be a difficult task to create on your own, but fortunately there are several different implementations available. I have experience with [Angular Virtual Scroll ngRepeat directive](https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat) but there are others out there that work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is not advised to load 5000 records at once and try to display the same in the browser. You need to do use paging. You cannot load some heavy data onto browser. It might crash or does not respond. Use paging to bring only 10/20/30 records at a time and provide paging buttons , so user can click and navigate to the desired page.

An article on how you can do paging: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/server-side-pagination-using-angularjs-web-api-and-sql-server/
--If you are using WebAPI

Comment: Agreed. Even doing 100 at a time shouldn't be too bad. One should also consider having a search box to locate or filter the results. There are plenty of assisting packages out there to help you paginate; I tend to favor bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination

Comment: A filter would be the best thing in terms of usability, as we are not showing everything in single page

Comment: I agree but  after loading those records .I want to send a common msg to all of them within a minute. so i need all users  to display

Comment: You are trying to load the records onto browser ? What message has to be sent to users? If you can elaborate on the requirement, would be easy to answer.

Comment: consider a panel ,where am having users list , on  click of ALL (checkbox).All users should be selected then send a common msg to selected users.

Comment: You can have a seperate button, which says "Send to ALL". In the button click, you just read all users info from DB, on server and just send the msg from there. This way you don't need to bring all the users data at once on to UI. And just simply use paging to display paged user info on the UI.

Comment: Also one more button you can add, which says "Send to selected users", then select only few users on the UI and send. This will be helpful if you wish to send the msg to limited set of users